# jQuery - Hide show not working properly in Chrome (Works only once)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, show-hide

Just wrote a jquery to show a comment button, when click on the textarea. Hide comment button clicking on somewhere else in the screen. **Its working fine in Firefox. But in Chrome it working only once.** When I click on textarea again the submit button is not showing, its still hidden.

```
$(document).on('click', ".comment_txt, .comment_btn", function() {
  var post_id = $(this).attr("post-id");      
  $("#comment_btn_div_"+post_id).show();
});
$('body').click(function() {
  $(".comment_btn").hide()
});


<form class="comment_submit" action="http://localhost:3000/api/v2/posts/48774/comment" data-post-id="48774" id="comment_form_48774">
    <textarea post-id="48774" id="comment_txt_48774" placeholder="Comment" cols="40" rows="1" class="width100 comment_txt"></textarea>
    <div id="comment_btn_div_48774" class="right comment_btn" post-id="48774" style="display:none">
      <button onclick="$(this).text('commenting...')" class="btn btn-small btn-info right" id="comment_btn_48774" type="submit">Comment</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Not sure why this is not working in Chrome. There are many form in my page. So I have did  `$(".comment_btn").hide()` on body click. In order to show a particular comment button i'm using this code `$("#comment_btn_div_"+post_id).show();`

Update:

After the comment button is hidden, Even when i do a $("#comment_btn_div_23232").show() from firebug console. Its not showing the div.

Update 2 (testing with alert):

```
$(document).on('click', ".comment_txt, .comment_btn", function() {
  alert("commenttext area clicked");
  $(".comment_btn").show()
});
$('body').click(function() {
  alert("body clicked");
  $(".comment_btn").hide()
});
```

1. Clicked textarea, got alert a. body clicked b. commenttext area clicked. Now comment button is shown
2. Clicked body got alert a. body clicked. Now Comment button is hidden
3. Clicked textarea, got alert a. body clicked b. commenttext area clicked. Now comment button is **not shown**.

Thanks!

Comment: div "comment_btn_div_48774" is the part of your body.

Comment: yes its the part of body

Comment: Works fine for me. Do you get any errors?

Comment: No i'm not getting any errors. Please note that there are many form in my page. So I have did $(".comment_btn").hide(). In order to show a particular comment button using this code $("#comment_btn_div_"+post_id).show();

Comment: Why you have bind your click event with ".comment_btn" also as its a part of div.

Comment: `post-id` isn't a valid html attribute. I'm guessing you wanted to use `data-post-id`. I tried it in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/sVpCT/1/) and the code you provided works. Can you add more and try to reproduce the problem here?

Comment: @Abhishek When i click on comment_btn, the div should not hide. So i have added it.

Comment: @Spokey - In the link that you have given when i click on body, Comment button is not hiding.

Comment: I have updated my question. The second time even when i do it from firebug its not showing the comment box in Chrome

Comment: where u placing the " $("#comment_btn_div_23232") " element.. does the parent od the element display is block or not..u r using className for representing elements so some where ur parent element of required element getting hide.. please check this...

Comment: @Srikanth are you sure you clicked right? http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/sVpCT/3/

Comment: Hi @Gauti, the textarea and comment_btn have the same parent which is not hidden. Also the parent is not hidden, when i try to do show that div from firebug its not working. Not sure why. This happens only in chrome

Comment: @spokey: http://jsfiddle.net/sVpCT/4/ I'm not able to reproduce in jsfiddle :( Works fine in jsfiddle but my project still has problems.

Comment: @Srikanth then the problem may be somewhere else since there is no real problem with this code :/ try setting an alert and see if it gets the right `post_id`, or add some `console.log()` and see if you get the values.

Comment: @Spokey - Updated my question with example.

Comment: Have you checked how many times ur ID is repeating.please use unique ID.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with blur

```
$(document).on('click', ".comment_txt, .comment_btn", function () {
    var post_id = $(this).attr("post-id");
    $("#comment_btn_div_" + post_id).show();
});

$('.comment_txt').blur(function () {
    $(".comment_btn").hide()
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/sVpCT/5/)

Comment: $('.comment_txt').blur(function () { alert(1); }); Blur not working in Chrome. I'm not getting alert for this code. Show() is working. This is my Chrome Version 23.0.1271.97. Using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I run into this every once in a while. Have yet to figure out why it happens; it befuddles me. I solve it by using one of the other ways of "showing" divs. Most recently, I changed the css display property:

$("#comment_btn_div_"+post_id).css('display','block');

Answer (score -1):

```
var post_id=null;
$(document).on('click', ".comment_txt, .comment_btn", function(event) {
  post_id = $(this).attr("post-id");      
   $("#comment_btn_div_"+post_id).show();
   event.stopPropagation();

   $('body').bind("click",function() {
        $("#comment_btn_div_"+post_id).hide()
        $(this).unbind();
   });
});
```

I hope it will work for you

Comment: Sorry this code works fine in Firefox. But its still the same in Chrome. Works for the first time. Second time the comment button is not showing up.

Comment: I have updated the code would you please chceck. I am not sure about your page structure.As I think other things will hinders it.In js fiddle the code working fine.

Comment: would you please check by putting alert in textarea click and body click.. does that click is working or not. Does the call will happening or not.

Comment: Updated my question with example